# System.UnauthorizedAccessException while deleting dll

Tags: c#, .net, exception

While deleting my .dll file System.UnauthorizedAccessException was thrown.

```
System.IO.File.Delete("file name here.dll");
```

Error message is as follows:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'E:\Projeler\Spa Anahtar Üretici\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\AutoGen.dll' is denied.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Probably you have no rights to access the folder or the dll is used by some process

Comment: Yes you are right. May be I have no rights to delete it. Buthow to delete it? Also File.SetAttributes(filename, FileAttributes.Normal); doesn't work too. And I have tried change file security.

Comment: If you are don't have access to delete the folder, run it as someone who does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the file using File.Open method and enclose it in try-catch with exception IOException.

If the file is in use , the code flow reaches the exception part and hence don't delete the file, Otherwise you can safely delete.

Comment: Now it is not being use by another program. I need for administrative privilages.

Comment: This may not be the right approach.But give it a try. Try opening the file in write mode.In that case it will throw unauthorized exception if you dont have permuission. Use that flow to check if the file can be deleted or not

Comment: OK, I solved problem from your tips. Initially, system warned me by unAuthorizedException. But after creating streamWriter I got "File in use" message. Thanks...

Comment: Hi again, After solving problem no exception occurs. But dll file remains undeleted.

Comment: deleting the file isn't throwing you exception?